# Passport.js Stateless

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm using Passport.js local strategies to handle auth in my app. I'm also using Nodemon to automatically refresh the server whenever I make changes.

Problem is whenever I make changes I have to login again to the application. For now this is just development but the same concept would apply to multiple servers handling the requests (ex. EC2 load balancer). So my question is, how can I make Passport.js stateless while still preserving the state of the user?

Seems like there has to be a way to preserve the state across servers and/or restarts of the server.

Comment: Why is it important for this application to be stateless exactly? You could propagate state information if that's what you're worried about - I don't quite see how it gives you a benefit. Just trying to help you avoid [asking an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In production I plan on using EC2 load balancers so basically using different servers maybe for every request so I need to make sure a user is authorized even if the login request took place on a separate server. I don't want the user to have to login every time they want to make a request for every new server. Then in development it's becoming a pain every time I make a change and Nodemon restarts the server to have to re sign in. I could be totally wrong but seems like pretty much the same solution will fix both problems.

Comment: Store your authentication related data on redis server. So, server restart will not flush your authentication data and caching will be much faster on redis server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use a persistent session store e.g. [MongoDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo), [Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis), or [PostgreSQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple)
2. Do not use sessions at all, use JSON Web Tokens aka JWT instead.

First option requires less setup if you already have a shared database, just instantiate the store and pass it to you app, eg:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```

The second option requires a different Passport strategy like [passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) or maybe ditching Passport completely and using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) directly in a custom middleware.

Comment: Great detail. Thanks so much.